# What is blackberry's default browser name

Tags: android, browser, blackberry, windows-phone

Please any one help me to know about **BlackBerry** default browser name and also **Android**'s

About Andriod's default browser:- copied from http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e83fd93d9e9be07a

"Its generally referred as "Chrome Lite". But its not the official
name."

For windows phone it is **Internet Explorer** (IE or MSIE).

Comment: For **iPhone** it is Safari and **SAMSUNG Bada OS** is Dolphin.

Comment: But, I added all phones (WP and android...)

Comment: A default Android browser is mainly speaking, named a `stock` browser, especially pre-blink browsers. The windows phone's is referred to as *IEMobile* as per its user-agent. The Blackberry browser has no given name. I just call it *Blackberry*. Same goes for Ubuntu Mobile and Sailfish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For blackberry and android devices they are both referred to as browser. On android you can have firefox and dolphin. Android uses a webtool kit based browser, so pretty much anything should work on it.

Comment: So, there is no specified name for it. I search in google, I got same thing with few more words. "No name, it called as Blackberry Browser"